# How can i increase the font size of codeigniter captcha helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha, helper

I am using the **codeigniter** **capctha** helper. The thing is I can not increase the font size of letters. I tried to do it by

```
if ($use_font == FALSE)
{
    $font_size = 6;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/2));
    $y = 0;
}
else
{
    $font_size = 20;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
    $y = $font_size+2;
}
```

but nothing happens, how can change the font size, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You are changing the correct parameter, whether in the core file or the application/helpers file.

Double check the font that you are using.  Some fonts have one size and that is it.  The default font file (texb.ttf) has only one size (? I think...).

I am using the following configuration:

```
//----- Captcha Implementation -----
$this->load->helper('captcha');

$captchaSetup = array(
    'img_path'   => './captcha/',
    'img_url'    => base_url()."captcha/",
    'font_path'  => './assets/fonts/E004007T.TTF',
    'img_width'  => 250,
    'img_height' => 50,
    'expiration' => 7200
);

$capData['cap'] = create_captcha($captchaSetup);
```

Pick a font file and place it in the fonts folder and try it out.

Comment: Yes it seems that the default font (texb.ttf) only has one size. I tried to change to another font and everything runs good.

Answer (score 0):

You may use "true type" fonts in captha's `font_path` to get a bigger size. Try to set `path/to/your/ttfont.ttf` in `font_path` and then pass a greater value to `font_size`. It should work!