# codeigniter captcha helper is not increasing text font size

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

This seems a duplace question some how, but its not.
Am asking the following :

1. Does the codeingiter helper does have a font size increasing feature ? even if i passed the following array setting seems not change.

   'font_size' => 36

2.The font i used has the following font sizes , but still no change to captcah size

[image]

So what is the matter ?

```
/* Setup config to pass into the create_captcha function */
                $capache_config = array(
                    'img_path' => 'captcha/',
                    'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
                    'img_width' => '150',
                    'font_path' => base_url() . 'captcha/font/captcha4.ttf',
                    'img_height' => 40,
                    'expiration' => 7200
                );

                /* Generate the captcha */
                $captcha = create_captcha($capache_config);
```

But the size is i can't get it larger even if i increased width or height ? 
Any thing you know about this ?

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389029/how-can-i-increase-the-font-size-of-codeigniter-captcha-helper

Comment: seems duplicated but question wise the above doesnt provide how they have configured their settings to generate the captcha ? and still no answer

Comment: Check the font that you are using  some fonts having one size . Try to change your font

Comment: can you please give your website link

Comment: see this may also happen because of cache system ,  i  tried     editing     your image on firebug and able to change images width and height ,plese empty the cache and check

Comment: `font_path` should be server file path, not the url to the font. change `base_url()` with `FCPATH . 'captcha/font/captcha4.ttf'`.

Comment: @machineaddict ,@Karthick Kumar Thankyou all i found a brilliant solution out of your comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easier solution :)

1.Goto this file `yourapplication`->`system`-`helpers`->**captcha_helper.php**

2.Find the following line and apply change as you want i.e we change font size of the default captcha font size helpers settings.

**NB.You can move the entier file to you application/core and suffix the file  with MY.**

**$font_size    = 28; //edited font for captcha size modification**

```
   // -----------------------------------
    //  Write the text
    // -----------------------------------

    $use_font = ($font_path != '' AND file_exists($font_path) AND function_exists('imagettftext')) ? TRUE : FALSE;

    if ($use_font == FALSE)
    {
        $font_size = 5;
        $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/3));
        $y = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        $font_size  = 28; //edited font for captcha size
        $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
        $y = $font_size+2;
    }
```

3.Clear catch on your testing browser
4.Modify helper configuration on your controller or other places like **FCPATH IS A MUST** Thanks **machineaddict**!

```
 $capache_config = array(
                'img_path' => 'captcha/',
                'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
                'img_width' => '290',
                'font_path' => FCPATH . 'captcha/font/captcha4.ttf',
                'img_height' => 65,
                'expiration' => 7200
            );
```

Expected Output :

[image]

BANG BANG I HIT THE GROUND !!!!

Comment: Changing system files is very bad practice. NEVER do it! You cannot upgrade CodeIgniter anymore, unexpected results can happen, etc. That's why extending CodeIgniter system classes, helper, etc exists.

Comment: so move it to core folder on application folder your modification will replace the core folder in systems

Answer (score 7):

Codeigniter captcha helper doesn't allow to change the font size. The following will replace the default `create_captcha` function and allow you to change the font size. The CodeIgniter version I have used is 2.2.0. This is working/tested code.

**Step 1:** Create a new helper file named `MY_captcha_helper.php` and save it under  at the root of CodeIgniter folder in `application/helper`. Content of the file:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * CodeIgniter
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2008 - 2014, EllisLab, Inc.
 * @license     http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/license.html
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com
 * @since       Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * CodeIgniter CAPTCHA Helper
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Helpers
 * @category    Helpers
 * @author      ExpressionEngine Dev Team
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/xml_helper.html
 */

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Create CAPTCHA
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   array   array of data for the CAPTCHA
 * @param   string  path to create the image in
 * @param   string  URL to the CAPTCHA image folder
 * @param   string  server path to font
 * @return  string
 */
if ( ! function_exists('create_captcha'))
{
    function create_captcha($data = '', $img_path = '', $img_url = '', $font_path = '')
    {
        $defaults = array('word' => '', 'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '', 'img_width' => '150', 'img_height' => '30', 'font_path' => '', 'expiration' => 7200, 'font_size' => 5);

        foreach ($defaults as $key => $val)
        {
            if ( ! is_array($data))
            {
                if ( ! isset($$key) OR $$key == '')
                {
                    $$key = $val;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $$key = ( ! isset($data[$key])) ? $val : $data[$key];
            }
        }

        if ($img_path == '' OR $img_url == '')
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! @is_dir($img_path))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! is_writable($img_path))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if ( ! extension_loaded('gd'))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        // Remove old images
        // -----------------------------------

        list($usec, $sec) = explode(" ", microtime());
        $now = ((float)$usec + (float)$sec);

        $current_dir = @opendir($img_path);

        while ($filename = @readdir($current_dir))
        {
            if ($filename != "." and $filename != ".." and $filename != "index.html")
            {
                $name = str_replace(".jpg", "", $filename);

                if (($name + $expiration) < $now)
                {
                    @unlink($img_path.$filename);
                }
            }
        }

        @closedir($current_dir);

        // -----------------------------------
        // Do we have a "word" yet?
        // -----------------------------------

       if ($word == '')
       {
            $pool = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

            $str = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
            {
                $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
            }

            $word = $str;
       }

        // -----------------------------------
        // Determine angle and position
        // -----------------------------------

        $length = strlen($word);
        $angle  = ($length >= 6) ? rand(-($length-6), ($length-6)) : 0;
        $x_axis = rand(6, (360/$length)-16);
        $y_axis = ($angle >= 0 ) ? rand($img_height, $img_width) : rand(6, $img_height);

        // -----------------------------------
        // Create image
        // -----------------------------------

        // PHP.net recommends imagecreatetruecolor(), but it isn't always available
        if (function_exists('imagecreatetruecolor'))
        {
            $im = imagecreatetruecolor($img_width, $img_height);
        }
        else
        {
            $im = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height);
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Assign colors
        // -----------------------------------

        $bg_color       = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);
        $border_color   = imagecolorallocate ($im, 153, 102, 102);
        $text_color     = imagecolorallocate ($im, 204, 153, 153);
        $grid_color     = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 182, 182);
        $shadow_color   = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 240, 240);

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the rectangle
        // -----------------------------------

        ImageFilledRectangle($im, 0, 0, $img_width, $img_height, $bg_color);

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the spiral pattern
        // -----------------------------------

        $theta      = 1;
        $thetac     = 7;
        $radius     = 16;
        $circles    = 20;
        $points     = 32;

        for ($i = 0; $i < ($circles * $points) - 1; $i++)
        {
            $theta = $theta + $thetac;
            $rad = $radius * ($i / $points );
            $x = ($rad * cos($theta)) + $x_axis;
            $y = ($rad * sin($theta)) + $y_axis;
            $theta = $theta + $thetac;
            $rad1 = $radius * (($i + 1) / $points);
            $x1 = ($rad1 * cos($theta)) + $x_axis;
            $y1 = ($rad1 * sin($theta )) + $y_axis;
            imageline($im, $x, $y, $x1, $y1, $grid_color);
            $theta = $theta - $thetac;
        }

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Write the text
        // -----------------------------------

        $use_font = ($font_path != '' AND file_exists($font_path) AND function_exists('imagettftext')) ? TRUE : FALSE;

        if ($use_font == FALSE)
        {
            $font_size = $font_size != 5 ? $font_size : 5;
            $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/3));
            $y = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            $font_size = $font_size != 5 ? $font_size : 16;
            $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
            $y = $font_size+2;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++)
        {
            if ($use_font == FALSE)
            {
                $y = rand(0 , $img_height/2);
                imagestring($im, $font_size, $x, $y, substr($word, $i, 1), $text_color);
                $x += ($font_size*2);
            }
            else
            {
                $y = rand($img_height/2, $img_height-3);
                imagettftext($im, $font_size, $angle, $x, $y, $text_color, $font_path, substr($word, $i, 1));
                $x += $font_size;
            }
        }


        // -----------------------------------
        //  Create the border
        // -----------------------------------

        imagerectangle($im, 0, 0, $img_width-1, $img_height-1, $border_color);

        // -----------------------------------
        //  Generate the image
        // -----------------------------------

        $img_name = $now.'.jpg';

        ImageJPEG($im, $img_path.$img_name);

        $img = "<img src=\"$img_url$img_name\" width=\"$img_width\" height=\"$img_height\" style=\"border:0;\" alt=\" \" />";

        ImageDestroy($im);

        return array('word' => $word, 'time' => $now, 'image' => $img);
    }
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------

/* End of file captcha_helper.php */
/* Location: ./system/heleprs/captcha_helper.php */
```

I have changed:

this

```
$defaults = array('word' => '', 'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '', 'img_width' => '150', 'img_height' => '30', 'font_path' => '', 'expiration' => 7200);
```

into this

```
$defaults = array('word' => '', 'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '', 'img_width' => '150', 'img_height' => '30', 'font_path' => '', 'expiration' => 7200, 'font_size' => 5);
```

and this

```
if ($use_font == FALSE)
{
    $font_size = 5;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/3));
    $y = 0;
}
else
{
    $font_size = 16;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
    $y = $font_size+2;
}
```

into this

```
if ($use_font == FALSE)
{
    $font_size = $font_size != 5 ? $font_size : 5;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/3));
    $y = 0;
}
else
{
    $font_size = $font_size != 5 ? $font_size : 16;
    $x = rand(0, $img_width/($length/1.5));
    $y = $font_size+2;
}
```

**Step 2:** Create a folder named `captcha` at the root of CodeIgniter folder (you might already have it) and give it permissions 755 under apache current user/group.

**Step 3:** Save your .ttf custom fonts under `captcha/fonts`.

**Step 4:** Your controller code:

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');

$capache_config = array(
    'img_path' => 'captcha/',
    'img_url' => base_url() . 'captcha/',
    'img_width' => 190,
    'img_height' => 60,
    'font_size' => 20,
    'font_path' => FCPATH. 'captcha/font/verdana.ttf',
    'expiration' => 7200
);

/* Generate the captcha */
$captcha = create_captcha($capache_config);

if ($captcha !== FALSE) {
    echo $captcha['image'];
} else {
    die('No captcha was created');
}
```

**Step 5:** Example output:

[image: captcha file]

Comment: Brilliant but i have the easier solution now :)

Comment: much better idea than hacking the core.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Codeigniter Captcha Helper documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/captcha_helper.html), the native GD font has a size limit. You have to specify your own font to change the size:

> font_size defaults to 16, the native GD font has a size limit. Specify a “true type” font for bigger sizes.

In my case, I downloaded a font from Google Fonts, saved it in my public html directory under my assets folder, and changed the font path to:

```
'font_path'     => '../html/assets/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf',
'font_size'     => 16,
```

And now I can change the font with the font_size attribute as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding texb.font which lies in the system/fonts folder. Actually the issue is of font path. Below is the code:

```html
    $vals = array(
            'img_path'      => FCPATH.'uploads/captcha/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'uploads/captcha/',
            'font_path'     => FCPATH.'system/fonts/texb.ttf',
            'img_width'     => '250',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'expiration'    => 7200,
            'word_length'   => 4,
            'font_size'     => 40,
            'colors'        => array(
                    'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
                    'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
                    'text' => array(0, 0, 0),
                    'grid' => array(255, 40, 40)
            )
        );
```

Below is the result:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu5l6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just use a different font file then font_size is working:

```
'font_path'     => dirname(FCPATH) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'fonts'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'Arial.ttf',
```